# Was the 2012 Finnish film Iron Sky shown in full in Germany despite the multiple uses of Swastikas?

Tags: censorship, iron-sky

The Nazi comedy-satire movie Iron Sky features numerous swastikas throughout - on uniforms, buildings, artworks etc.

As per [German law post-war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika#Germany):

> The German and Austrian postwar criminal code makes the public showing of the Hakenkreuz (the swastika) and other Nazi symbols illegal and punishable, except for scholarly reasons. It is even censored from the illustrations on boxes of model kits, and the decals that come in the box. Modellers seeking an accurate rendition often have to either stencil on the marking, or purchase separate decals.

This film had its [premiere at the Berlin Film Festival](http://www.filmofilia.com/iron-sky-premieres-in-berlin-film-festival-87795/) but I cannot find out if it was shown in full, or if there was a recut version replacing the swastikas with something else (unlikely, they're pretty engrained in the film), or whether their use was just blurred?

Are Swastikas now just shown in movies when released in Germany despite being technically illegal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I saw the film and I clearly remember seeing some swastikas.

I think in Film and art it is generally tolerated that swastikas are shown, e.g. in `Indiana Jones` and `Inglorius Basterds` (although there is no swastika on the dvd casing for Inglorius Basterds)

According to [this document from the Bundesprüfstelle](http://www.bundespruefstelle.de/bpjm/redaktion/PDF-Anlagen/bpjm-aktuell-hakenkreuze-film-fernsehen-computerspielen-aus-03-10,property=pdf,bereich=bpjm,sprache=de,rwb=true.pdf):

> Wesentlich problematischer und zudem in Rechtsprechung und Schrifttum
> weitgehend unbehandelt sind entsprechende Kennzeichenverwendungen in
> fiktionalen Unterhaltungsmedien wie insbesondere Spielfilmen und
> Computerspielen. Die auch häufigere Veranschaulichung von Hakenkreuzen
> in bekannten und populären Action- und Abenteuerfilmen wie „Indiana
> Jones” oder jüngst dem Tarantino-Streifen „Inglourious Basterds” wird
> in der Regel allgemein geduldet, wobei die Subsumtion solcher in
> erster Linie dem reinen Entertainment dienender Filme unter die
> Sozialadäquanzfälle des § 86 Abs. 3 StGB kaum gelingt. In der Praxis
> tendenziell restriktiver ist demgegenüber die Handhabung der
> Kennzeichenverwendung bei Computerspielen, in denen in der Regel schon
> die kurze einmalige Visualisierung eines verfassungsfeindlichen
> Kennzeichens i.S.d. § 86a StGB auf Grund vereinzelter
> obergerichtlicher Rechtsprechung zu Beginn des Computerspielzeitalters
> erhebliche Risiken der Beschlagnahme und Strafverfolgung mit sich
> bringt.

.. the showing of swastikas is tolerated in modern media (films and computer games).

An [answer on gutefrage.net](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/iron-sky---hakenkreuz) states the same:

The restriction generally does not apply to the use in [...], Art, [...].

> Der Film muss auch keinen dokumentarischen Sinn ergeben. Relevant sind
> die §§ 86 und 86a StGB. Diese sagen nicht nur aus, dass man
> Kennzeichen bzw. Propagandamittel von verbotenen Organisationen
> prinzipiell erstmal nicht verwenden darf, sondern auch dass diese
> Verobt nicht gilt, wenn die Verwendung "der staatsbürgerlichen
> Aufklärung, der Abwehr verfassungswidriger Bestrebungen, der Kunst
> oder der Wissenschaft, der Forschung oder der Lehre, der
> Berichterstattung über Vorgänge des Zeitgeschehens oder der Geschichte
> oder ähnlichen Zwecken dient."
>
> Da der Film eindeutig als Kunst zu werten ist, ist die Verwendung von
> Hakenkreuzen oder anderen ansonsten verbotenen Symbolen ganz klar
> erlaubt.

If a more literal translations is required please let me know :)

#### Further reading/information:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strafgesetzbuch_section_86a

Comparison of English Blu Ray (with swastika) vs. German Blu Ray (without swastikas):

[image]

This is the German Cover for Inglorius Basterds without the swastika:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I think this is what I would have assumed; that the usage of them is just slightly more tolerated now (depending on the context). I highly doubt any politician is going to actually *revert* the law to make it official. I can't imagine it going down well in the German parliament (Bundestag?) for someone to say "OK, it is no longer illegal to show swastikas". That'd probably be political suicide!

Comment: @JonW it is actually still a very complicated issue, anti-nazi organisations had to fight for the right to produce and sell ant-nazi stickers, that contained the swastika. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strafgesetzbuch_section_86a